# HTML5 video tag not playing in Firefox

Tags: html, html5-video

I have a MVC/.NET project and I set the mimetype in my webconfig:

```
<staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".m4v" mimeType="video/m4v" />
</staticContent>
```

Then I added this video tag to my webpage

```
<video width="640" height="385" controls="controls">
      <source src="/videos/sample_mpeg4.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
      <object data="/videos/sample_mpeg4.mp4" width="640" height="385">
        <embed src="movie.swf" width="640" height="385" />
      </object>
    </video>
```

And I open this webpage in Firefox, but I get the message "no video with supported format and MIME type found".
If I open `http://localhost/videos/sample_mpeg4.mp4` Firefox opens the download window, so it means the video path is correct.

I searched in Stackoverflow and google and this brought me to my current status, but now I am stuck. 
Can someone help me troubleshooting this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox does not support the MP4 format within its video tag. The main reason why is the royalty fee attached to the mp4 format.

Check out [Media_formats_supported_by_the_audio_and_video_elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Media_formats_supported_by_the_audio_and_video_elements) directly from the Mozilla crew or the following blog post for more information:

http://pauljacobson.org/blog/2010/1/22/firefox-and-its-limited-html-5-video-support.html

Comment: just found that out too! thanks for the help. I downloaded an ogv file and it worked :)
I will accept your answer as soon as I am able to

Comment: +1 - might be a good idea to reference multiple video sources as described in: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_audio_and_video_in_Firefox